# How to ignore messages from disconnected channel

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I'm implementing simple netty server for a multiplayer game. I'm just trying to figure out Netty.

I test the server via telnet. What i done is broadcast the messages to all channels. It's working smoothly. Also I remove channels from map on close event which is fine.

But the problem is if one of the clients disconnect unexpectedly, before closed callback, messageReceived callback called which the sender is disconnected channel.

How can i properly ignore the message comes from disconnected client?
I use `StringBuffer` in `messagedReceived` but for the case `StringBuffer.toString` is also not a proper string. At the end disconnected channel broadcast pointless message to other channels and itself, when receiver channel is itself throws an exception `Connection reset by peer`
which it's normal because the channel itself is not available at the moment.

Here is the code ;

```
     @Override
     public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("------------------");


            Channel current = e.getChannel();
            System.out.println("SenderChannel:"+current.getId());

            if(!current.isOpen())
                System.out.println("Not Open");

            ChannelBuffer buf = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();

            StringBuffer sbs = new StringBuffer();

            while(buf.readable()) {
                sbs.append((char) buf.readByte());
            }

            String s = sbs.toString();


            System.out.println(s);

            String you = "You:" + s;
            String other = "Other:" + s;



            byte [] uResponse = you.getBytes();
            byte [] otherResponse = other.getBytes();


            Iterator iterator = channelList.entrySet().iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                  Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();

                  Integer key = (Integer)pairs.getKey();
                  Channel c = (Channel)pairs.getValue();

                  System.out.println("ReceiverChannel:"+c.getId());

                  if(key != current.getId())
                      c.write(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(otherResponse));
                  else
                      c.write(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(uResponse));

            }

     }


    @Override
    public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
            ChannelStateEvent e){

        Channel ch = e.getChannel();


            channelList.remove(ch.getId());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("*****************");
            System.out.println("DisconnectEvent:"+ch.getId());
            System.out.println("*****************");
            System.out.println();
            ch.close();

    }
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the question and an answer to it: You could use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer. You do not need synchronization   in the scope where it is used.

Comment: StringBuilder makes sense, but for the rest of your comment, i didnt get that?

Comment: :) Synchronization needs resources. So using a not-thread-safe class where synchronization is not needed will save you some cpu%

Comment: ok i see but what about the answer the question @Fildor

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have one. Except to adopt Soroush's concept. I fthe connection itself is not your "state" of user being logged in or out, you'll have to keep a context observing that state and you'll have to check that state and filter messages accordingly when writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't solve the problem in the manner that you would like. If there's a network problem then technically the sender could disconnect at any time, for example

- as soon as the thread enters messageReceived
- while you're iterating through channelList
- while you're iterating through channelList but after you've echoed back to the sender
- after you've broadcast the message

Netty can't raise the disconnected event while messageReceived is processing because you're running in the thread that will raise the event (unless you have a non-ordered execution handler in your pipeline). The correct solution really depends on your application. If the broadcast results in all the other receivers responding it's probably better / easier to have the server suppress any messages destined for a client that's no longer connected.

Also, if you're really going to use strings then take a look at StringEncoder / StringDecoder. There's no guarantee in your code that the message event buffer contains a complete string.

Comment: thanks man what did solve my problem is using StringEncoder / StringDecoder in pipeline. now disconnecting has not seen in messageReviced because of decoding phase. probably it's ignored because of decode.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a try/catch around each send. If one of them fails, close the corresponding channel.

Comment: I dont need to because already override the exceptionCaught. But the problem is disconnecting channel couldnt throw an exception during send the others. others can get the meaningless messages. Only exception throws when it tried to send message itself(peer disconnected).. If i didnt echo back to itself, i couldnt catch the exception.

Comment: @tylerdurden I cannot make head or tail of any of that, but if you encounter any exception other than a timeout when doing I/O on a socket, it is as dead as a doornail and you must close it.

Comment: yeap right man, that's what i'm doing in the exceptionCaught.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a multiplayer game server, it might be better to use an existing Netty game server solution like [java game server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server). Disconnects become events which get sent to the [session](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server/blob/master/jetserver/src/main/java/org/menacheri/jetserver/app/impl/DefaultSession.java) and since it is event driven, you could write your own [handler](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server/blob/master/jetserver/src/main/java/org/menacheri/jetserver/event/EventHandler.java) to decide whether or not to receive anymore events on the same session. Since events are queued in a FIFO order, if disconnect happens then you need not go ahead with subsequent broadcasts.

Comment: looks like interesting, i'm definitely gonna look it.

Comment: how about the question by the way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Java Developer. But from socket point of view this data is in buffer or sent before disconnecting of user. So when you are in receiving stage user is still connected and exactly on time of completing of receiving user is already disconnected. So I think best way to prevent this things is to check if user is still connected after each receiving of data.

In C# I personally use this code to check if user is still connected:

```
if (client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
{
    byte[] checkConn = new byte[1];
    if (client.Receive(checkConn, SocketFlags.Peek) == 0)
        return false;
}
return true;
```

I am not sure about Java And Netty (And if your connection is TCP) but this is what I use and this could be possible to convert it easily to Java.

Comment: That only determines whether the client has closed the connection cleanly, and it's rather expensive. It would be better to just handle the send errors as they occur: that way you find all disconnections, not just the graceful ones, and you don't need two extra system calls to do it.